# Deflate gzip'ed blob when copying it to Azure file share

Tags: c#, azure

I have a SAS uri from a blob containing Content-Encoding set to gzip and Content-Disposition set to rename the downloaded file. This works fine when accessing the link through the browser. What I want to achieve however is copy the file over to an Azure File share (StartCopyAsync) using the said blob SAS uri. This works, but the end result on the file share isn't decompressed like when downloaded through the browser.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Copy operation will not automatically decompress the content for you. It will simply copy the raw data and properties from source blob to destination file.

If you want to have the decompressed content in file storage, you will have to write the code to do that. You would need to write the code to download the blob, decompress its contents and then upload the decompressed content in file storage.

Comment: That sounds highly inefficient. Especially if you don't have the memory or the local temp storage.

Comment: AFAIK, that's the only way. I am curious to understand your use case. Why would you want to keep the content compressed in blob storage but uncompressed in file storage?